# Pivot Table in MySQL not returning correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

I know this question have been asked few times and I am trying to do exactly what the accepted answers are but obviously I am doing something wrong and can not get the desired output.

I would like to return data in following format:

Name  |  27-06-2015 |  28-06-2015

===== |  ========== |  ==========

John  |  6:30AM     |   7:30 AM

Steve |  6:00 AM    |   4:00 AM

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

but when I run the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b762/6) query I  do not get any data for the next day in the attendance table. If I remove grouping I get the data for the next day but a new row is inserted in the resultset:

Name  |  27-06-2015 |  28-06-2015

===== |  ========== |  ==========

John  |  6:30AM     |   null

John  |  null       |   7:30 AM

Steve |  6:00 AM    |   null

Steve |  null       |   4:00 AM

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The sql I am using is :

```
SELECT 
 Name,
 case(dropoffdate) when '20150627' then CONCAT(DropoffTime, ' - ', PickupTime) end as '2015-06-27',
 case (DropoffDate) when '20150628' then CONCAT(DropoffTime, ' - ', PickupTime) end as '2015-06-28'
 FROM
 Student s
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Attendance a on s.id = a.student 
 GROUP BY s.id
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b762/6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `MAX` or `MIN` group function as desired, to fetch valid record.

```
SELECT 
       Name,
       MAX( case(dropoffdate) 
                 when '20150627' 
                      then CONCAT(DropoffTime, ' - ', PickupTime) 
            end ) as '2015-06-27',
       MAX( case (DropoffDate) 
                 when '20150628' 
                      then CONCAT(DropoffTime, ' - ', PickupTime) 
            end ) as '2015-06-28'
 FROM Student s
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Attendance a on s.id = a.student 
 GROUP BY s.id
```